# Google Play Services DriveApi call to upload a local file

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-drive-android-api, google-drive-api

With Google APIs Java Client you can synchronously upload a file to Drive with

```
    mDriveService.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
```

Is there an equivalent function with the new Android's Google Play Services DriveApi?
It seems that you can only upload new files with something like this:

```
    Contents newContents = Drive.DriveApi.newContents(mGoogleApiClient).await().getContents();
    OutputStream outStream = newContents.getOutputStream();

    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(myLocalFile);
    byte[] data = new byte[16000];
    while ((nRead = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
         outStream.write(data);
    }
    outStream.close();

    MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                    .setTitle(fileContent.getName())
                    .setMimeType(mimeType)
                    .build();
    DriveFileResult createResult = destFolder.createFile(mGoogleApiClient, changeSet, newContents).await();
```

My problem with the above code is that if the local file I want to upload is very big (think about a recorded video, for example) it force you to duplicate the file on device's storage and this create big problems in some cases.